# How to get ng-repeat to re-render when shared $scope changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three controllers inheriting from one main controller which contains data. I'm representing the array in each ng-repeat with a function call, and I'm guessing that's the reason the lists don't update after changes to the model.

Other info: To give you an idea of the model-- topics are nested in groups, and rules are nested in topics. So when I select a group, I want to show only the topics for the group, and when I select a topic, I want only the rules for that topic to show.

Any idea why the lists don't re-render when the selected group/topic change?

(Selected classes update on click, so I know it's firing.)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="DataCtrl">


    <div ng-controller="GroupCtrl">
        <nav>
            <h4>Groups</h4>
            <ul ng-repeat="group in getGroups()">
                <li><a href="#" ng-click="selectGroup($index)"
                    ng-class="selectedGroupClass($index)">{{group.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>

    <div ng-controller="TopicCtrl">

        <ul ng-repeat="topic in getTopics()">
            <li><a href="" ng-click="selectTopic($index)"
                ng-class="selectedTopicClass($index)">{{topic.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div>
    <div ng-controller="RuleCtrl">

        <ul ng-repeat="rule in getRules()">
            <li ng-click="selectRule($index)"
                ng-class="selectedRuleClass($index)">{{rule.text}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>


</div>




</div>
```

Here are the controllers:

```
   angular.module('paxApp').controller("DataCtrl",function($http,$scope){

        $scope.data = [{topics:[{rules:[]}]}];

        $http.get('js/data/userData.json').success(function(data) {

            $scope.data = data;

            console.log("user data",$scope.data);
        });

        $scope.selectedGroup = 0;
        $scope.selectedTopic = 0;
        $scope.selectedRule = 0;

    });

angular.module('paxApp').controller("GroupCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.selectedGroup = 0;

    $scope.getGroups = function(){
        return $scope.data;
    };

    $scope.selectGroup = function(index){

        $scope.selectedGroup = index;
        console.log($scope.selectedGroup);
    };

    $scope.selectedGroupClass = function(index) {

        return $scope.selectedGroup === index ? "group-selected" : "";

    };


});

angular.module('paxApp').controller("TopicCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.getTopics = function() {

        return $scope.data[$scope.selectedGroup].topics;
    };

    $scope.selectedTopicClass = function(index) {

        return $scope.selectedTopic === index ? "topic-selected" : "";
    };

    $scope.selectTopic = function(index) {

        $scope.selectedTopic = index;

    };

});

angular.module('paxApp').controller("RuleCtrl",function($scope){

    $scope.getRules = function() {

        return $scope.data[$scope.selectedGroup].topics[$scope.selectedTopic].rules;

    };


    $scope.selectRule = function(index) {

        $scope.selectedRule = index;

    };

    $scope.selectedRuleClass = function(index) {

        return $scope.selectedRule === index ? "rule-selected" : "";

    };

});
```

Comment: Maybe the function is not being re-evaluated because there is no parameter change in the function call. Try passing the indexes as parameter. For example: `ng-repeat="rule in getRules(selectedGroup, selectedTopic)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your bindings in your child controllers, this is easily resolved by putting your scope vars into an object. Make sure to fix your references and it will work.

`$scope.my = { selectedGroup :0, selectedTopic :0, selectedRule :0};`

cheers

Comment: ah! That was it! I was just reading about that as a common gotcha, but didn't put two and two together. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Dan Doyon beat me to the actual problem, but I would regardless like to add the following.

Your idea of using a controller as a data controller isn't really the Angular way: Controllers are most of all View Controllers. In your case I would rewrite DataCtrl as a Service and inject it in the (view) controllers where needed. This allows you to bind $scope variables to the Services variable to keep everything updated.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataService', function ($scope, DataService) {
    $scope.varThatNeedsData = DataService.data;
}]);

// Init is intended to be used for the resolve property in the $routeProvider. 
app.service('DataService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = {};

    self.init = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('data/url').then(function (response) {
            self.data = response.data;
            deferred.resolve();
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    };

    return self;
}]);
```

Comment: upvote for being so helpful, even though Dan was right. Thanks for the tip. It always felt a little weird to be using a Controller to pull in the data.

Comment: @KG-Christensen you are absolutely spot on for the point about making a service, i was a bit lazy and only addressing the core issue. kudos for improving answer